# Can you please guide me what's wrong in the code?

Tags: java, android

The line in MainActivity.java in which WorkoutDetailFragment is casted shows error that it cannot be done. Please tell me why it isn't working. I copied the code from a book.

MainActivity

```
package gangster.workout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
    frag.setWorkout(1);
}
}
```

Workout.Java

```
package gangster.workout;


public class Workout {
private String name;
private String description;

public static final Workout[] workouts = {
        new Workout("The Limb Loosener" , " Pta nhi kya ksgdrna hai isme") ,
        new Workout("The Timb Loosener" , " Pta nhi kya asdfasasfasasdkrna hai isme") ,
        new Workout("The Pimb Loosener" , " Pta nhi kyaasf krna hai isme") ,
        new Workout("The Zimb Loosener" , " Pta nhi kyasfasa krna hai isme") ,
};
private Workout(String name , String description){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public String toString(){
    return this.name;
}
}
```

WorkoutDetailFragment.java

```
package gangster.workout;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {
private long workoutId;

public void setWorkout(long id) {

    this.workoutId = id;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();
    if (view != null) {
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        Workout workout = Workout.workouts[(int) workoutId];
        title.setText(workout.getName());
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
        description.setText(workout.getDescription());
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Dude, it works. Thank you. What was wrong in using that one though?

Comment: your code indicates that you're using `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and both are from the android support library. which requires getting the correct `FragmentManager` by calling `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Please accept the answer since it solves your problem :)

Comment: I'm a beginner. Can you please explain a bit more un-sophisticatedly? :P
I can accept the answer after 4 minutes.

Comment: The Android team offers a [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) which provides backward-compatible versions of new features. for example `Fragments` were introduced in API v11, but using the support library you can use it in API v4 and up. you can read this part in the link I provided, you'll get the idea.